# Как реализовать цепочку localStorage -> Redux store -> View на Реакте?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Суть приложения в том, что есть список контактов в таблице и нужно осуществлять с ними crud-операции.

Это client-side приложение. Данные "типа прилетают из бэка", но на самом деле они в json-файле лежат в папке приложения и оттуда их собираюсь аксиосом доставать.

Нужна именно в таком порядке цепочка, чтобы данные для редаксовского хранилища брались из localStorage. Мне думается, что в юзеффекте надо делать аксиосом запрос на файл и засунуть полученные данные в localStorage.

А как именно связать localStorage со стором редакса? Именно, чтобы когда обновлял данные в каком-то поле, то сначала это вносилось в localStorage, а уже оттуда они шли в стор и таким образом обновлялся UI. Точно также и с удалением, чтобы данные соответствующего поля из localStorage очищались и пропадали из стора.

Для добавления контакта думаю по клику на Add contact button вызывать модалку с полями для заполнения (с названиями как заголовки таблицы), а данные из этих полей опять же в localStorage, а оттуда в стор. И таким образом добавляется новый пункт таблицы.

Может есть какие-то видео или статьи, чтобы посмотреть? Просто везде инфа как данные из стора сохранять в ls, но не наоборот.

Набросал в экселе схематично как приблизительно должно выглядеть приложение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]